# Ocultar DIV o variable en una condicional sólo si el resultado del loop no existe. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php 

$title = '<h4 class="viveres-tag">' . 'Víveres' . '</h4>'; ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<?php 
        if (is_tax($WCMp->taxonomy->taxonomy_name)){
            $vendor_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
            if ($vendor_id){
                $vendor = get_wcmp_vendor_by_term($vendor_id);
               echo $title;
            echo '<div class="viveres"';
            $args = array(
            'author' => $vendor->id,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order' => 'desc',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'terms' => 'proteinas',// categories
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                )
            )
        );
        echo '</div>';
    // End query
      }
}
        $products = new WP_Query( $args, 'wcmp_product_category'); ?>
        
<?php   if (have_posts()):
            while ($products->have_posts()):
                $products->the_post();
                
                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
</div>
</div>
```

En el código anterior estoy haciendo un loop personalizado para llamar y obtener resultados de una categoría de productos específica de un usuario, el código funciona "bien" pero estoy tratando de hacer que, si la categoría de productos no existe o no hay disponibilidad de stock no muestre el h4 ($title).

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas simple es agregar css a la etiquete H4

```
<h4 style="display:<?php echo $muestraonomuestra;?>;"</h4>
if($hayproductos==true){
$muestraonomuestra="block";
} else{
$muestraonomuestra="none";
}
```

Comment: Hola @leo gracias por comentar. Solo para entender mejor el código que escribiste, la variable '$hayproductos' a qué se refiere?